# Register and display real time tracking of my smartphone (gps) on a map

Tags: web-mapping, gps, tracking

I have 2 smartphones (android galaxy and iphone) and i would like to display the position, according to the gps coordinates, on a map.

Is there any app to download or any kind of service where i could register? Every time I start the app, the coordinates of the smartphone would be sent to some web service and few seconds later that actual position would be displayed on a map. The map should be accessed/viewed by a user from a desktop pc through a normal Internet Browser.

edit: any known open source projects where you could setup your own "tracking system" and expand/modify it?

Comment: Hey new to live tracking excellent app

Comment: U keep track of my locations even if my phone is off or doesn't have WiFi enabled??

Answer (score 6):

[Find my Friends](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/find-my-friends/id466122094?mt=8) for iPhone and [Google Latitude](http://www.google.com.au/intl/en_au/mobile/latitude/) for both platforms do that.

You will need an Apple account for Find my Friends or a Google account for Google Latitude.

Comment: thx, do you know if they also store the data so I can check a specific timeframe in the past?

Comment: No, I don't think they do. Just live positions unless they can't get a current fix in which case it will use the last known position (at least I know Find My Friends does this)

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check out OsmAnd project ([main page](http://osmand.net/), [code/wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/osmand/)) from the [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand&hl=en) store.  While I have not personally tried their [Live Tracking method as described in their HowTo](http://code.google.com/p/osmand/wiki/HowToArticles#How_To_Setup_own_live_tracking), it appears as though it may accomplish the task you are looking for.

- My favorite thing about OsmAnd... you can download offline files for
  use without internet connection.
- My biggest gripe... I cannot figure out how to display my GPS track
  in real-time on the device (I can only get it to display after I manually "save" the current track).

Answer (score 2):

An option for Android phones is the [Real Time GPS Tracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greenalp.RealtimeTracker)

Comment: can you expand on your answer and tell the poster WHY you believe this is a good option for their needs?